# v-combobox - performance issue on large list with custom item appearance

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-combobox with a custom appearance for the list of item via the item slot.

```
  <v-combobox :items="items"...>
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <mycustomcostlycomp :item ="item"/>
    </template>
  </v-combobox>
```

My issue is that as I type in the combobox, the list is filtered and each item in the list will be re-rendered - a costly operation for the custom component I am using.
How can I avoid it to re-render? Each item has already been rendered and it should just be a matter of hiding some of them depending on what I type.

Apart from the performance issue it is working as expected.

EDIT: codepen=https://codepen.io/olivierkrener/pen/MWKebOv

I added 2 counters, one for the number of time each value is mounted and one for the number of value change within the components. As you type in the box, you will see both increasing even if the data is all static. How do I avoid the re-rendering of the components? Why are the values changing?

In my app, both a component first rendering and a value change (via a watch) will cause some costly processing.

EDIT2: I added a key prop as suggested and the watcher is not triggered anymore :). But still the components are rendering again and again,

Comment: Have you tried placing unique keys to your custom component? Also is it possible to create a codepen?

Comment: Please post a complete code example

Comment: Codepen added, first time using it...